# Bags of concrete mix labeled as containing 100 lb have a population mean weight of 100 lb

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Bags of concrete mix labeled as containing 100 lb have a population mean weight of 100 lb and a population standard deviation of 0.5 lb

a) Find probability that the mean weight of a random sample of 50 bags is less than 99.9 lb

This part was easy for me, i used the normal distribution model and got 0.0228 as the probability

b) Find the 5th percentile of the sample means

I don't know about this part, i know i'm supposed to use the normal distribution model but im not sure how to get the correct answer here

c) find the sample size so that no less than 99% of the sample means are within 0.05 of the true population mean

Comment: For part (a), I got about $.0786$.

Comment: Can you explain the steps you took to get to 0.0786?

Comment: Sure. I typed into my TI-84: normalcdf(-999,99.9,100,.5/sqrt(50)). The standard error for a sample of size $n$ is $\sigma/n$.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs - I suspect you intended to say that the standard error for a sample of size $n$ is $σ/\sqrt n$

Comment: Yes! I certainly did. Thank you; it’s harder to proofread my comments when posting from the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part (a).** If $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{50}$ is a random sample from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 100,\, \sigma = 0.5),$ then $\bar X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 100,\, \sigma = 0.5/\sqrt{50}).$

If you want to compute $P(\bar X \le 99.9),$ you can use the following approach, which allows you to use printed normal CDF tables for the last step:

$$P(\bar X \le 99.9) = 
P\left(\frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\le \frac{99.9 - 100}{0.5/\sqrt{50}}\right) = P(Z \le -1.414) =\, ??$$

You will have to round -1.414 (or interpolate) to use most printed tables.
The exact answer to four places from R statistical software is 0.0786, as
Commented by @GTonyJacobs. But your value from tables may be something like 0.0793, depending on the table you use (and exactly how).

```
pnorm(99.9, 100, .5/sqrt(50))
## 0.0786496
```

**Part (b).** The 5th percentile of the distribution of $\bar X$ is the number $q$ such that
$P(\bar X \le q) = 0.05.$

To find this from normal tables, write

$$P(\bar X \le q) = 
P\left(\frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\le \frac{q - 100}{0.5/\sqrt{50}}\right) = 0.05.$$

In your normal table, find closest available number in the *body* of the table 
to 0.05. Then find the value $c$ such that $P(Z \le c) = 0.05.$ Because
$c$ will be negative (depending on the style of printed table you are using),
you may need to find the value that cuts 0.05 from the *upper* tail of the
standard normal distribution, and then use symmetry to find $c.$ When you get $c$, Set $c = \frac{q-100}{0.5/\sqrt{50}},$ and solve for $q.$ The exact
value from software is shown below, but the potential for small rounding errors using tables is more serious here than in part (a), so do not expect to get *exactly* the value shown using tables.

```
qnorm(.05, 100, .5/sqrt(50))
## 99.88369         # exact q
qnorm(.05)
## -1.644854        # exact c
```

**Part (c).** Here I will give only a hint, because I don't know what
you have been studying recently.

A 99% confidence interval (CI) for $\mu$ is of the form
$$\bar X \pm 2.576\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}.$$
This is derived from the probability

$$P\left(\frac{|\bar X - \mu|}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \le 2.576\right) = .99.$$

The 'margin of error' of the CI is $E = 2.576\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$
Plug in known quantities and solve for $n;$ if $n$ is not an integer, round up.
I got something like $n=664.$

If you have a t-table in your textbook, you may want to know that the
bottom row of that table (perhaps marked: 'Inf, $\infty,$ or 'Norm')
is for the standard normal distribution. You may be able to get the z-value 2.576 from there. About the best you can do from printed *normal* tables (without interpolation) is 2.58. In answering, you should use only
values you can show how to get.

In the figure below, red dotted lines are relevant to part (a) and dashed cyan lines to part (b). In the normal probability plot, purple lines are at
$\pm 2.576.$

[image]

*Note:* I don't think the Chebyshev bound suggested in another answer to your question
is sufficiently accurate to get the answer you are supposed to provide.

Comment: but I believe there is nothing wrong in the methodology. Am I right?

Comment: Other than irrelevance, it looks fine. For practical purposes, there's quite a difference btw 664 and 1000. (I guess you _have_ shown $n$ doesn't have to be 1500.) I have always regarded Chebyshev approximations as fine for proving limit theorems, but not 'tight' enough for good probability approximations in practical problems. An inequality that applies to _all_ distributions (with finite variance) can hardly be relied upon to give a tight bound for any one specific distribution.

Comment: i have a question, i was given two formulas for the standard deviation (SD) by my professor: SD = SD * sqrt(n) and SD = SD/sqrt(n).... why did you use the second formula for the standard deviation and not the first? (for part A)

Comment: Nevermind, i understand everything, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

b)

$P(Z<=\frac{ \bar X - 100}{\frac{.05}{\sqrt{50}}}) = 0.05$

$\frac{ \bar X - 100}{\frac{.05}{\sqrt{50}}} = \Phi^{-1}(0.05)$

c) $P(|X-100|\le .05 ) \gt 0.99$

Using Chebychev's inequality

$P(|X-100|\ge .05 ) \le .01$

$P(|X-\mu| \ge \frac{k\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}) \le \frac{1}{k^2}$

Now equate these two expressions

$\frac{k\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} =.05$

But $ \frac{1}{k^2} = .01$

$k = 10$

$\sqrt{n} = \frac{10\times 0.5}{.05}$

$\sqrt{n} = 100$

$n = 10000$

Comment: (+1) for showing standard notation in (b), which is useful.